# How to use ComboBox SelectedValue in where clause

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, where-in

I try this code but in the `where` clause there's an error.

```
var subComTbl = from subCom in myDb.SubComTbls
where subCom.AuthorityID.ToString()== Authoritycombo.SelectedValue
select subCom;
SubComcombo.Visible = true;
SubComcombo.DataSource = subComTbl;
SubComcombo.DisplayMember = "SubComName";
SubComcombo.ValueMember = "SubComID";
```

Comment: Authoritycombo or subCom.AuthorityID is null

Comment: Let me know if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you should pay attention to compiler warnings.

> Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison,
>   cast the right hand side to type 'string'

The `SelectedValue` property is of type of object. You should use `Authoritycombo.SelectedValue.ToString()`

```
where subCom.AuthorityID.ToString()== Authoritycombo.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

Both operands of `==` should be of the same type, so if you use `subCom.AuthorityID` at left side, the other operand at right side should be of same type as `AuthorityID` or if you use `Authoritycombo.SelectedValue.ToString()` at left side the other operand at right side should be of type of string.

Comment: @MUAl-t yes, do it this way with ==

Answer (score 0):

You don't need convert `SelectedValue` and `subCom.AuthorityID` to string for comaring those values.

`SelectedValue` contains value of type same as type of Property(or Column) of DataSource

In your case, I assume `AuthorityID` and `SubComID` properties are Integers
So you need only check for null in `SelectedValue` before comparing

```
SubComcombo.Visible = true;
SubComcombo.DataSource = subComTbl;
SubComcombo.DisplayMember = "SubComName";
SubComcombo.ValueMember = "SubComID";

Int32 selectedID = -1; //default value which for sure not in the database
if(Authoritycombo.SelectedValue != null)
    selectedID = (Int32)Authoritycombo.SelectedValue;

var subComTbl = from subCom in myDb.SubComTbls
                where subCom.AuthorityID == selectedID 
                select subCom;
```